# How can I manually send GPS data to Location Manager on my android phone(rooted)

Tags: android, api, gps, locationmanager

My question is, How will actually LocationManager get data from GPS device on mobile?
 Can I manually give LocationManager data which i intended to give??
 For my testing I require such thing.
 Or Can anyone provide me details how or through which File will GPS device provide data to LocationManager.
 Or By what means will the Location API communicate with GPS device/ GPS driver.

I require some or the other information to provide direct GPS data to LocationManager inturn to the APPs using locationManager(Directly on mobile not by emulators).

Any help or suggestions are Appreciated.

Reagrds
Poorna Chander T

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice app for testing apps that require GPS:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1577485

Also you have to select "Allow mock locations" in developer options on your phone.

Comment: Thank you Marcin, But the thing is I wanna create a interface between a driver and LocationManager. So i require how to provide data to LocationManager. Or if possible give API to send inforamtion to location manager